# SQL - How to count records for each status in one line per day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table `Sales`

```
Sales
--------
id
FormUpdated
TrackingStatus
```

There are several status e.g. `Complete`, `Incomplete`, `SaveforLater`, `ViewRates` etc.

I want to have my results in this form for the last 8 days(including today).

Expected Result:

```
Date Part of FormUpdated, Day of Week, Counts of ViewRates, Counts of Sales(complete), Counts of SaveForLater
--------------------------------------
2015-05-19   Tuesday    3   1   21  
2015-05-18   Monday     12  5   10
2015-05-17   Sunday     6   1   8
2015-05-16   Saturday   5   3   7 
2015-05-15   Friday     67  5   32
2015-05-14   Thursday   17  0   5 
2015-05-13   Wednesday  22  0   9
2015-05-12   Tuesday    19  2   6
```

Here is my sql query:

```
select  datename(dw, FormUpdated), count(ID), TrackingStatus 
from Sales
where FormUpdated <= GETDATE()
AND FormUpdated >= GetDate() - 8
group by  datename(dw, FormUpdated), TrackingStatus
order by  datename(dw, FormUpdated) desc
```

I do not know how to make the next step.

### Update

I forgot to mention, I only need the Date part of the `FormUpdated`, not all parts.

Comment: please add table structure and sample data properly

Comment: hi @ImranAliKhan the table structure is the same as the one I described in the 1st line of my post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `SUM(CASE WHEN TrackingStatus = 'SomeTrackingStatus' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))` to get the status count for each tracking status in individual column. Something like this. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6361d/13)

```
select  
CONVERT(DATE,FormUpdated) FormUpdated,
DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(DATE,FormUpdated)),
SUM(CASE WHEN TrackingStatus = 'ViewRates' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c_ViewRates,
SUM(CASE WHEN TrackingStatus = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c_Complete,
SUM(CASE WHEN TrackingStatus = 'SaveforLater' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) c_SaveforLater 
from Sales
where FormUpdated <= GETDATE()
AND FormUpdated >= DATEADD(D,-8,GetDate())
group by  CONVERT(DATE,FormUpdated)
order by  CONVERT(DATE,FormUpdated) desc
```

Comment: Hi ughai, your answer is closer than mine, but it does not aggregate counts for a same day. In order words, it display records for e.g. Tuesday many lines. Please see my update.

Comment: @Franva - Yes i forgot to remove the `group by TrackingStatus`. see updated answer

Comment: hi it still display records for one day, I think it's because the FormUpdated in the group by clause. But I do not know how to remove it while still keep the FormUpdated in the final result.

Comment: hi @ughai, in my database, I use datetime to define the FormUpdated. so that's the reason why it still displays several records per day.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was date only. let me update the answer based on this new information

Comment: hi @ughai, one more thing to add for this question, is it possible to list the days which do not have any records and just display all 0s for these days(rows)?  Or do you prefer to answer this in another question?

Comment: @Franva -you can construct a numbers table and then do a date add with getdate() and then join with your sales table like numbers left join sales on numbers.date = formupdated

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255) to achieve this result - you'll just need to complete the list of `TrackingStatus` names in both the `SELECT` and the `FOR`, and no `GROUP BY` required:

```
WITH DatesOnly AS
(
  SELECT Id, CAST(FormUpdated AS DATE) AS DateOnly, DATENAME(dw, FormUpdated) AS DayOfWeek, TrackingStatus
  FROM Sales
)
SELECT  DateOnly, DayOfWeek, 
        -- List of Pivoted Columns
        [Complete],[Incomplete], [ViewRates], [SaveforLater]
FROM DatesOnly
PIVOT 
(
   COUNT(Id)
   -- List of Pivoted columns
   FOR TrackingStatus IN([Complete],[Incomplete], [ViewRates], [SaveforLater])
) pvt
WHERE  DateOnly <= GETDATE() AND DateOnly >= GetDate() - 8
ORDER BY DateOnly DESC
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ffc45/7)

Also, I think your ORDER BY is wrong - it should just be the Date, not day of week.

Comment: Hi Stuart, I tried yours in the SqlFiddle, it works, but when I executes it against my own data, it display several records per day.

Comment: @Franva I think FormUpdated may be a DateTime, hence it is grouping by unique times as well. I've updated  to cast back to a `DATE` only.

Comment: hi @StuartLC, one more thing to add for this question, is it possible to list the days which do not have any records and just display all 0s for these days(rows)? Or do you prefer to answer this in another question?

Comment: @Franva It will generally be quicker (and better for SO community) for you to have posted a new question - we are in different timezones :) The common approach to empty data is to generate a range of dates (e.g. from a Dates Table, or a recursive CTE) and then left outer join from this to your data. I've used [another CTE in this updated SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ffc45/11)

Comment: thanks StuartLC, I've got it and your solution looks better when generating the dates. Cheers!